# assign "val" for unit test in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit, mockk

I am writing unit tests in kotlin, for this purpose I need to assign value on a "val", here is the simplified version of the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Request")
data class Request(

    @Column(name = "Name")
    val name: String,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long? = null

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "Created")
    val created: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
}

@Test
fun `test one`() {
    val name = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(10)
    val id = Random.nextLong(100)
    val created = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(48)
    
    val request = Request(playerUid = playerUid).apply {
        id = id
        created = created
    }
}
```

it has an compile error when assigning "created" in the test. How should I manage this unit test since I need to set my desire "created" value? (I can not touch any part of the "Request class")

Comment: Just move it as constructor property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change any part of the `Request` class then you will not be able to change `created`.

You will either need to test `created` by using an approximate test range (`created` needs to be 0<now<2s sort of thing)

It is a design flaw to encode a static accessor to functions like `LocalDateTime.now()` - this should be set externally in a service class.  If you really cannot do that, then here is another hacky approach:

1. add a CLOCK object somewhere (does not need to be in a companion object) but ultimately you have to change the `created` assignment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Request")
data class Request(
    @Column(name = "Name")
    val name: String,
) {
    companion object {
        /** used for carrying a Clock only in the case of tests **/
        val CLOCK = ThreadLocal<Clock>()
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long? = null

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "Created")
    val created: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(CLOCK.get() ?: Clock.systemUTC())
}
```

Normally you don't touch that `CLOCK` but in the Unit Tests you define a

```
private val fixedClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2022-08-29T08:20:50Z"), ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

then you need

```
@BeforeEach
fun beforeEach() {
    // this is necessary because the serialization of MemberMentorCommon.weeksOnPlan uses a clock
    CLOCK.getOrSet { fixedClock }
}

@AfterEach
fun afterEach() {
    CLOCK.remove()
}
```

Yes, ThreadLocals are nasty, but this allows you to change the behaviour of the Request class to override the `now()` function